# I set evaluate=False, buy SymPy's parse_expr still evaluates the expression

Tags: python, sympy, evaluate

I'm trying not to evaluate the expression, but it's being
evaluated anyway.

This:
`parse_expr("sqrt(I**2)", evaluate=False)`

Returns this:
`i`

Why is this happening? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: The `evaluate=False` argument only has a limited effect and there are many functions that will still evaluate such as `sqrt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than relying on the flag, try parse the string in a context:

```
>>> from sympy.core.parameters import evaluate
>>> with evaluate(0):
...  parse_expr('sqrt(I**2)')
...
sqrt(I**2)
>>> _.args
(I**2, 1/2)
```

Comment: This is parsing the values without evaluating, but when I check the difference between two values which are same, it is not returning zero.
The two values are:
(5*6)*dfrac
(5*6)*dfrac
and when I check the difference, it shows like, -5*6*dfrac + (5*6)*dfrac, which is not zero.

Comment: Perhaps you could open a separate thread for that so your input and output is more clear.